# openni2.launch fails with ROS Indigo, USB3.0

Tags: xtion, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With my configuration, openni2.launch and openni.launch are fails and I have no idea for the reason.
Could you help me ?

When I launch openni2.launch, I have an error as follows.

`process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [11714]

[ INFO] [1412458420.971125192]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.

process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [11735]

[ INFO] [1412458421.138822800]: Device "1d27/0600@1/9" with serial number "" connected

[ INFO] [1412458421.143513223]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason:
 openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Device::OpenNI2Device(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.1-0trusty-20140921-1358/src/openni2_device.cpp @ 74 : Initialize failed

    Could not open "1d27/0600@1/9": Failed to set USB interface!`

My laptop is MacBookPro and it has only USB3.0 ports, No USB2.0 port ...
Someone suggests to use "ASUS Xtion USB 3.0 Hotfix, however it seems that I need Windows OS.
I don't have it.

The configuration is as follows.

1. OS : Ubuntu 14.04
2. ROS : Indigo
3. PC : MacBookPro(USB3.0 x 2, USB2.0 x 0, including Mac OS X and Ubuntu 14.04)
4. tried packages : openni.launch, openni2.launch
5. Used device : Xtion Pro Live

What should I do ?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194193/openni2.launch-fails-with-ros-indigo,-usb3.0/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2014-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the older xtion (0600), you should definitely be running openni.launch unless you get the hotfix installed. You could try running windows in a VM or using someone else's computer, it's a pretty quick process.

You could also try fiddling with the [endpoints](http://answers.ros.org/question/61211/problem-with-xtion-pro-live-and-openni_camera/?answer=61212#post-id-61212).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2014-10-06**:
My xtion is the older version and openni.launch cannot also work well. It generates error(Failed to set USB Interface!)...
Actually, xtion worked with Mac OS X, NiViewer can be shown.

I fiddled with the endpoints but it doesn't work...

Can I get hotfix installed with only Ubuntu ??

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-06**:
Not afaik. The error is probably due to USB3 incompatibility. You could also try removing xhci (http://www.pcl-developers.org/xhci-hcd-I-hate-you-USB-3-0-and-Primesense-Asus-Xtion-td5707949.html), but this seems like a lot more trouble than running windows in a vm.